# How to know if an element is actually appeared in browser and can seen by human's eye?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 |---header of html ----|
 |----------------------|
 |----------------------|
 |----------------------|
 |----------------------|  not displayed in browser
 |----------------------|
||----------------------|| <-----------
||----------------------||
||----------------------|| 
||----------------------|| browser, the part that human 
||----------------------|| actually see
||----------------------||
||----------------------|| <------------
 |----------------------| 
 |----------------------|  not displayed in browser
 |----------------------|                 
 |----------------------|                 
 |----------------------|                 
 |----------------------|                 
 |----------------------|                 
 |----------------------|
 |-----end of html------|
```

How to know if an element is actually appeared in browser and can seen by human's eye?

jquery's `visible` seems cannot do this.

Comment: You should trick with scroll and/or offset.

Comment: 5min implementation: (looks like it works)
function isVisible(DOMObj) {
    var visibleStart = window.scrollY;
    var visibleEnd = visibleStart + $(window).height();
    var $dom = $(DOMObj);
    var objStart = $dom.offset().top;
    var objEnd = objStart + $dom.height();

    if ((objStart > visibleStart && objStart < visibleEnd) || (objEnd > visibleStart && objEnd < visibleEnd)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: @VisioN What existing question?